# fwrite UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: php, byte-order-mark

To write data to file encoded in UTF-8 (with BOM):

```
function writeStringToFile($file, $string){
  $f=fopen($file, "wb");
  $string="\xEF\xBB\xBF".$string; // UTF-8
  fputs($f, $string);
  fclose($f);
}
```

How do I write data encoded in UTF-8 without BOM?

### Edit

A screenshot from notepad++ with encodings:

[image]

Comment: Just don't add the BOM (\xEF\xBB\xBF)?

Comment: i think that would be simple ANSI...

Comment: @ihtus: a file without BOM is just a set of bytes. It's up to a software that processes it about how to treat them.

Comment: "a screenshot from notepad++ with encodings:" --- now open a file in a HEX editor.

Comment: @ihtus: I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
function writeStringToFile($file, $string){
    $f=fopen($file, "wb");
    // $file="\xEF\xBB\xBF".$file; // UTF-8 <-- this is UTF8 BOM
    fputs($f, $string);
    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: To be precise: `$file` variable wasn't even used :-)

Comment: O! really =) Time to sleep xD I think, there must be smth like

    $string="\xEF\xBB\xBF".$string;

Comment: Okk, then need just cut 3 first bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is removing the BOM after creating the file.

`<?php 
// change the pathname to your target file which you want to remove the BOM 
$pathname = "./test.txt"; 
$file_handler = fopen($pathname, "r"); 
$contents = fread($file_handler, filesize($pathname)); 
fclose($file_handler); 
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){ 
    $bytes[$i] = ord(substr($contents, $i, 1)); 
} 
if ($bytes[0] == 0xef && $bytes[1] == 0xbb && $bytes[2] == 0xbf){ 
    $file_handler = fopen($pathname, "w"); 
    fwrite($file_handler, substr($contents, 3)); 
    fclose($file_handler); 
    printf("%s BOM removed. 
\n", $pathname); 
} 
?>`

Answer (score 0):

The string `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` match the «UTF-8 with BOM» format.

If you have a string with this format and want to write it in a file with a «simple» UTF-8, you have to remove theses characters. This can be done in various way, for example with `preg_replace` :

```
function writeStringToFileUTF8($file, $string){
  $string = preg_replace("`\xEF\xBB\xBF`", "", $string);
  // this is equivalent as fopen(w)/fputs()/fclose()
  file_put_contents($file, $string);
}
```